# How to install Spanish language capabilities to swap with English

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

After fixing problems yesterday doing a fresh install of the newest distro (Thanks everyone), I was wondering if anyone out there has any experience with installing the necessary language packages to switch between English and Spanish quickly. The other research I've seen is people wanting to make the switch permanent which is why I'd like to be able to switch between them. If this has already been solved I apologize I just didn't find it.

I'm bilingual and I sometimes write in both. It would also be great if someone could point me to a good Libre Office dictionary and spell check extension. I've found one but it's not all that accurate.

Comment: You can install and switch to any languages in System Settings > Language Support. LibreOffice will use any of the installed dics. You can set the system language simply by dragging it to the top of the list. This has nothing to do with your keyboard layout.

Comment: Are you talking about the language in which messages and menus are displayed? If so, there is no 'quick' way to switch. You need to relogin to make the new language effective. The input language, OTOH, can be changed easily. Please clarify.

Comment: I see. I did want to do that, however just getting it to spellcheck and use a word processor would be fine. Is there any way to switch the apps over to Spanish all at once like Thunderbird without changing the entire systems language?

Comment: By default apps use the system defaults including language, unless unavailable for the given apps in which case it defaults to English. Some apps can be configured to override the system default, many can't. And, obviously, it must be done to each and every one.

Answer (score 2):

For Libre office, you can install a spell-checker with:

```
sudo apt-get install hunspell-es
```

Comment: Thank you I think that is what I was having trouble with. The spellchecker was very hit or miss, it seems to be doing better after now.

Comment: @SomaComa You're still not understanding: 1) Installing a new language installs all the available spell-checkers for that language, like the above, and 2) Installing a language doesn't mean you need to change your system language. As a matter of fact you can install all the languages you want, the system language will always be the one at the top of the list and no other.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings Language support system settings. The procedure is similar to this (Step 2 onwards)
https://planetadiego.com/2015/12/07/tutorial-cambiar-el-idioma-en-modo-live-de-un-pendrive-ubuntuunetbootin/

Comment: It would have been better if you mentioned the steps along with the link, focusing only on what's relevant for the case. Only half way down the article is.

Comment: My English is not good enough to write the explanation, and I'm not clear if answers are allowed in Spanish

Comment: Puedo hablar espanol.

Comment: Pero el resto del foro no